# Symfony - StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I use the query builder of Symfony and I have this query:

```
->select('partial detail.{id}')
->from('Shopware\Models\Article\Detail', 'detail')
->innerJoin('detail.attribute', 'attr')
->leftJoin('detail.article', 'article')
```

Now I have a custom model outside of this scope with the following relation:

```
class Supplier {
    /**
     * @var \Shopware\Models\Article\Supplier
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Shopware\Models\Article\Supplier")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fp_demand_planning_supplier_manufacturers", joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplier_id", referencedColumnName="id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="manufacturer_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)})
     */
    private $manufacturers;
```

On the article side the model `\Shopware\Models\Article\Supplier` is stored in `article.supplier`.

So now I want to join my custom model with the query above as follows:

```
->select('partial detail.{id}')
->from('Shopware\Models\Article\Detail', 'detail')
->innerJoin('detail.attribute', 'attr')
->leftJoin('detail.article', 'article')
->innerJoin('FpDemandPlanning\Models\Supplier', 'fps', 'WITH', 'article.supplier = fps.manufacturers');
```

Here I get this error:

```
206 near 'manufacturers': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

I also tried it this way:

```
->innerJoin('FpDemandPlanning\Models\Supplier', 'fps', 'WITH', 'article.supplier IN (fps.manufacturers)');
```

But then I get this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 216: Error: Expected Literal, got 'fpSupplier' in
```

Does anybody know how I can join a custom model that has a many to many relation here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `->innerJoin('article.supplier', 'supplier')->innerJoin('supplier.manufacturers', 'fps');`

Comment: @yceruto This does not work, because the model Shopware\Models\Article\Supplier has no association manufacturers ... $manufactors is defined in FpDemandPlanning\Models\Supplier ...